# Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver): "E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am getting:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-distutils'
```

If i do

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
```

Any ideas?

**Why?**

Because when I try to create an environment with pipenv and python3.8 I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

*pipenv* works with python3.7.

Comment: A distribution upgrade is probably in order as it seems that version 3.6.5-3 is the latest version available in the Bionic repository. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-distutils&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all